# How to get Default Data: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, fastapi, flask-restful

I am using python Fastapi,

```
class PropsCreate(PropsBase):
    id: str
    sender: str
    voice: str
    provider: Optional[str]
    destination: str = "/usr/local/"
```

The above class is inside a app/model/props.py and class is having a default value for **destination.**

I want to call that default value in app/api/endpoint/endpoints.py as below

```
from fastapi.routing import APIRouter

from app.models.props import (
    PropsBase
  
)
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/getdefaults", response_model=PropsBase)
def default_data():
    pass
```

How do I get that default value in the get route from PropsCreate class

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, why?

Comment: This will be integer ->id: str

Answer (score 1):

Generally there's (at least) two ways you can do this with the predefined [methods and fields on Pydantic models](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#model-properties):

You can use the `schema()` method to get a JSON schema compatible dictionary:

```py
>>> class PropsCreate(BaseModel):
...     id: str
...     sender: str
...     voice: str
...     provider: Optional[str]
...     destination: str = "/usr/local/"
...
>>> PropsCreate.schema()
{'title': 'PropsCreate', 
 'type': 'object', 
 'properties': {
     'id': {'title': 'Id', 'type': 'string'}, 
     'sender': {'title': 'Sender', 'type': 'string'}, 
     'voice': {'title': 'Voice', 'type': 'string'}, 
     'provider': {'title': 'Provider', 'type': 'string'}, 
     'destination': {'title': 'Destination', 'default': '/usr/local/', 'type': 'string'}}, 
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     'required': ['id', 'sender', 'voice']}
>>> PropsCreate.schema()['properties']['destination']['default']
'/usr/local/'
```

Or you can use `__fields__` to get the same information (since it has been documented in the public API you should be able to rely on this being available):

```py
>>> PropsCreate.__fields__
{'id': ModelField(name='id', type=str, required=True), 
 'sender': ModelField(name='sender', type=str, required=True), 
 'voice': ModelField(name='voice', type=str, required=True), 
 'provider': ModelField(name='provider', type=Optional[str], required=False, default=None), 
 'destination': ModelField(name='destination', type=str, required=False, default='/usr/local/')}
>>> PropsCreate.__fields__['destination'].default
'/usr/local/'
```

However, I suspect what you're trying to do is what the autogenerated openapi spec in FastAPI already does for you. If you access `/openapi.json` on your FastAPI instance, you'll get a JSON document back that conforms to the OpenAPI specification. This will include information about the expected parameters *and their default values* for any parameter (in this case under `components.schema.PropsCreate`):

```
destination: {
  title: "Destination",
  type: "string",
  default: "/usr/local/"
}
```

So if that's your goal, it might be better to use the built-in support instead of recreating what you're already getting for free with FastAPI.